# Auto-refresh news feed on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I want to refresh content in my BlackBerry app after 30 minutes.

Comment: A blackberry what? A web app targeted at blackberry users, a native client app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which screen if you want to update for that screen write like this:

```
public LoadingScreen()//This is constructor
{
         createGUI();
         callingThread();
}
public void createGUI()
{
         //write the all code here;
}
public void callingThread()
{
         Thread thread=new Thread()
         {
             Thread.sleep(3000);
             deleteAll();
             invalidate();
             createGUI();
         }
         thread.start();
}
```

Like this you can refresh the screen. Here "**invalidate()**" refresh the screen and createGui() add the contents to the screen again;